# Django Rest Framework add field to model before saving in viewset using ModelSerializer

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

Using Django Rest Framwork, I want to set a field that can not be null in the Database, but that's not included in the `fields` tuple on the Meta class, before i actually save the model that the ModelSerializer manages.

In my `ViewSet`, I define `perform_create` and want to do something like this:

`serializer.fields.new_field = new_field_id`

where `new_field` is a Foreign Key on my model and new_field.id is the id of the model i just fetched using a value set on the cookie.

Does anyone know a clean solution to this?

Thanks!

Comment: Checkout this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28665041/django-rest-framework-create-without-providing-a-foreign-key-value/28668626#28668626)

Comment: @Todor Another solution. Three already! Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean this..?

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

Comment: Hmm i tried that as well, it then tells me: `user is an invalid keyword argument for this function`.  I settled for a middleware solution where i modify `request.POST` on each `request.method == "POST"`. This works pretty good since i need to add the field to multiple resources and can depend on DRF's built in validators. It helps with DRY though i read it's not a great idea to modify `request.POST`

Comment: Ok shucks, PyCharm had me there. It suggested a different kwarg, i just realised the name of my model field was different from the one PyCharm suggested.. I appears i now have two valid solutions. Great & Thanks!